# Show value 2 digits after comma in RDLC

Tags: c#, excel, rdlc

I have a *RDLC report.* The value in my *RDLC report* is 4 digits after decimal place.
My aim is to display the value with 2 digits after decimal place.

But, when I export it to Excel the real value and I click at the cell is 4 digits after decimal place.

What I know is to set a value at Format in **TextBox** Properties in RDLC, but I don't know the value of the properties to achieve that.

Example:

```
Real Value: 1,000.4567
Displayed Value: 1,000.46
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Format property of the report text box to `#,##0.0000`

Comment: @user1008497 - If the answer helped you, please consider clicking the up arrow next to the answer. If the answer solved your question, please click the check mark under the down arrow. These things help others know your question is solved and which answers have helped, and your reputation will also increase.